# fetch не обрабатывает заголовок Set-Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookie

```js
const res = await fetch('/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Cookie: document.cookie
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

Вот кусок кода, который отправляет запрос на авторизацию. Авторизация проходит, и сервер отсылает заголовок set-cookie. Но кука не устанавливается (document.cookie = ""). Помогите в чем может быть проблема

Comment: credentials: 'include' тоеж не работает? fetch чем-то полифиллится или нативный?

Comment: Если в куках установлен флаг **httponly**, то javascript к ним доступа не получит!

Comment: Да, там стоит флаг httponly. А как тогда заставить браузер установить ее?

Comment: Если ставлю 'include', то fetch падает
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Авторизационные куки ставит сервер и соответственно проверяет их наличие при посещении сайта пользователем. Если вы дадите к таким кукам доступ из js, то считайте, что вас взломали. НО любой запрос от браузера в том числе с помощью js автоматически дополняется всеми куками текущего домена (и его родителя).

Comment: Смотрю наличие куки в cookie storage, там пусто. Браузер при запросе на сервер тоже не выставляет ее